# Try to redirect full domain but home to a specific url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect a domain to a new domain with same urls, but i need that the home (or '/') goes to an specific url.

i use that for redirect all with same structure

```
<IfModule https://mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://webantigua.com$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://www.webantigua.com$
 RewriteRule (.*)$ https://webnueva.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But i need a rule for home to go to `https://webnueva.com/web-antigua/`

What can i do?

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following Rules, written as per your shown attempts.
Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
<IfModule https://mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine ON
 ####OP's attempted rules here, with small fixes in them.
 RewriteCond HTTPS ON
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?webantigua\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$
 RewriteRule ^ https://webnueva.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

 RewriteCond HTTPS ON
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?webantigua\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^/?$ https://webnueva.com/web-antigua/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick answer, but it doesnt work. I clear all caches. Best regards.

Comment: @Regue, could you please do show me sample link which didn't work for you?

Comment: the home webantigua.com not redirect to https://webnueva.com/web-antigua/

Comment: @Regue, yes my rules should do that, what is happening when you hit it as of now?

Comment: Load normally webantigua.com and their urls, not apply any rule. Not go to webnueva

Comment: @Regue, ohh ok, got it, I have fixed it, please check it once and let me know if All is Well now?

Comment: Hi, but this redirect all url to same url in new domain, but home? i need home goes to webnueva.com/web-antigua/

Comment: @Regue, I think I added that previously, could you please check it edited rules and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: i try your code, but when i put on htaccess it doesnt work. Load always webantigua without redirect.

Comment: @Regue, ok lets do a small test, if your .htaccess file is working or not. Please do add a line `---------` into your htaccess file and try hitting any url if you get 500 internal error then means its enabled(htaccess file) else its not. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Yes, if i put ----- it get 500 internal error. Thank you.

Comment: @Regue, ok looks like `RewriteEngine ON` line was missing, I forgot to add :) I have added it now(please make sure its there in your htaccess file), could you please check now and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: @Regue, any errors you are seeing in browser OR in logs? then please do let me know.

Comment: No, no errors, only that like i change all in htaccess for that, permalinks of wordpress is broken, but its nrmal because i change htaccess to a new one, but not see errors.

Comment: could you help me in chat?